# Removing multiple slashes from path

Tags: c, strings, file-system, linux, windows

I have been trying to write a sample code block to remove multiple backward or forward slashes from a path (e.g. `//a//b` should be `/a/b`; on Windows, `c:\\a\\b\\\c` should be `c:\a\b\c`).

I am assuming that:

1. Code must be platform independent
2. Should work in all cases (or report a proper error)
3. It should be readable and maintainable
4. It shouldn't be over-complex and shouldn't have errors

Please provide point-wise comments for the following code sample (you may ignore `main` and assume that `path` is not `NULL` - it is just for demonstration purposes). Or else you may provide a better mechanism for the same.

```
    void
    die( int error_code, char* message )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, message );
        exit( error_code );
    }

    /*Following function removes duplicate slashes from a given path*/
    char*
    validate_path ( char* path )
    {
        char* path_copy = path;
        int dup_flag = 0;
        char* path_without_dup_slash = (char*)malloc(strlen(path)+1);
        if ( path_without_dup_slash == NULL ) {
             die( EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to allocate memory for processing path.");
        }
        char* copy_pwds = path_without_dup_slash;
        /* Travel through given path */
        while( *path_copy != '\0' ) {
              /* If there is '\' or '/' then copy a single '/'
               * , ignore others until a real char comes */
               if ( (( *path_copy == '\\') || ( *path_copy == '/' )) && 
                    (dup_flag == 0) ) {
                    *copy_pwds = *path_copy;
                    dup_flag = 1;
                    copy_pwds++;
                }else if (( *path_copy != '\\') && ( *path_copy != '/' ))  {
                    *copy_pwds = *path_copy;
                    dup_flag = 0;
                    copy_pwds++;
                }
                path_copy++;
         }
         *copy_pwds = '\0';
         path_without_dup_slash = (char *)realloc( path_without_dup_slash, 
                                  strlen( path_without_dup_slash ) + 1 );
         if ( path_without_dup_slash == NULL ) {
               die( EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to allocate memory for processing path.");
         }
         return path_without_dup_slash;
    }
    /*You please ignore the parts written in main - it is just for demonstration purpose. */
    int
    main( void ) {
         char* bad_path_1 = malloc(100);
         char* bad_path_2 = malloc(100);
         char* p1 = bad_path_1;
         char* p2 = bad_path_2;
         char* path_1;
         char* path_2;
         bad_path_1 = "//a//b//c";
         bad_path_2 = "c:\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c";
         path_1 = validate_path(bad_path_1);
         printf( "Good path:%s Bad Path:%s\n",path_1,bad_path_1);
         path_2 = validate_path(bad_path_2);
         printf( "Good path:%s Bad Path:%s\n",path_2,bad_path_2);
         free(path_1);
         free(path_2);
         free(p1);
         free(p2);
         return EXIT_SUCCESS;

     }
```

Comment: What should be returned for `/a///b`?

Comment: @SimonKirsten, `/a/b`. **Note that I'm not OP**.

Comment: It should remove just duplicate slashes, as posix says '/' is '//'. So it would be '/a/b'. But above function shouldn't block any valid path.

Comment: @Olzhas added code to demonstrate usage.

Comment: What about [UNC paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) like `\\ComputerName\Share\blah\zzx.txt`?

Comment: Note: if you are talking about POSIX paths, then you should be careful: paths starting with *exactly* two slashes have implementation-defined meaning. IOW: `///foo/bar` is the same as (and can be canonicalized to) `/foo/bar`, and `/foo//bar` is the same as (and can be canonicalized to) `/foo/bar`, but `//foo/bar`, `//foo//bar`, etc. can *not* be canonicalized. Their meaning is implementation-defined, and the "extra" slashes are semantically meaningful.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Agreed. Also, I am worried about valid path like `/a/b/\\\\c`

Answer (score 10):

Here are some suggestions for how you might improve your code.

### Use the appropriate `#include`s

This program fragment requires headers, which should be included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

### Use `const` where practical

Because the `validate_path` function does not alter the passed string, the parameter should be declared `const`:

```
char *validate_path ( const char* path )
```

### Don't make pointless copies of variables

When you pass a parameter to a function, it's a copy, so there's no reason for this line:

```
char* path_copy = path;
```

Just use `path` directly.

### Check for `NULL` before dereferencing

The first thing the `validate_path` does is to pass `path` to `strlen`, but this results in undefined behavior if `path` isn't a `'\0'`-terminated string.  A simple safety check would be to check to see if it's a NULL pointer and exit if it is.

### Consider a change to the interface

Instead of allocating memory within the function, consider instead altering the function so that it is passed an input and output buffer.  This way, the code would not need to allocate memory and the caller would do both allocation and freeing.  That makes for a more robust interface and it makes your code simpler.

### Prefer `for` to `while`

The `while` loop within the code would likely be more succinctly expressed as a `for` loop.  That way it's easier to see what is being iterated through and how.

### Use a more accurate function name

I would expect that `validate_path` would do just that and validate a path, but that's not really what's happening here.  Instead, it seems that a more accurate function name would be something like `remove_dup_slashes`.

### Simplify your code

Here's an alternative implementation that uses these suggestions:

```
char *validate_path(const char *path, char *curr) {
    if (path == NULL || curr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *begin = curr;
    // always copy first character
    *curr = *path;
    // if it's just a single `NUL`, we're done
    if (*curr == '\0') {
        return curr;
    }
    for (path++; *path; ++path) {
        // path points to next char to read
        // curr points to last written
        if (*curr != *path || (*curr != '\\' && *curr != '/')) {
            // only copy if not duplicate slash
            *(++curr) = *path;
        }
    }
    *curr = '\0';  // terminate string
    return begin;
}
```

Note that the interface is still not a very good one.  It could be improved by also passing in the length of the output buffer and maybe the length of the input buffer as well.

Comment: The proposed  change of interface is a good direction, but arguments to `validate_path` are in the wrong order. The destination array should come first and its size should be specified as a second argument: `char *validate_path(char *dest, size_t size, const char *path);`. It should be OK to pass the same address for `dest` and `path`.

Comment: @chqrlie: that's a reasonable alternative, but if you're going to argue that your suggestion is "right" and alternatives are "wrong," we'll have to differ on that. For example, see the standard [`void* memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) and note that the length is the third argument and not the second.

Comment: OK, I should have written *the order of arguments to `validate_path` is inconsistent with common C library usage*.  Regarding the destination size, it is passed after the pointer in `snprintf` and `fgets` and the `scanf_s` family.  The `count` argument in `memcpy()` is semantically different, as is the third argument in `strncat()`. It represents the number of elements to copy, not the size  of the destination array, which may be larger (and should be for `strncat()`)

Comment: @chqrlie: it's a fair comment and I agree.  I was trying to emphasize the evolutionary nature of the code (from OP's original to this one), but in real code, I would probably follow the convention you cite, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 9):

Your specification has holes in it.

What will be if user passes `NULL`? Undefined behavior? Return?

What if the path is already valid? Copy the string? Return itself? The latter case is probably unexpected, and will make following code to cause UB:

```
char* path = malloc(...);
char* valid_path = validate_path(path);
free(path); //tsunami is probably created by this line
```

I would use what C standard library does: it doesn't mess with memory allocations when doing something else (do note that `strdup()` is not standard C).

**Code Review:**

```
void
die( int error_code, char* message );
```

Strange. Why would you need this? Error handling in C is very clumsy, but in my opinion, if your function failed, it should return `NULL`. It is the best signal that function failed, so that *users will do what they want, not what you want on failure*.

```
char* validate_path ( char* path );
```

Since you're not marking `path` as `const`, I'd expect that you make changes in place. But you're saying "SURPRISE! I'll allocate memory!". If you're not modifying the source, mark it as `const`, it will tell the callers that you won't modify the input.

```
(char*)malloc(strlen(path)+1);
```

Redundant cast. `void*` is implicitly converted into any other pointer type.

```
/* Travel through given path */
```

Don't state the obvious. It just creates noise and disturbances while reading the code.

```
           if ( (( *path_copy == '\\') || ( *path_copy == '/' )) && 
                (dup_flag == 0) ) {
                *copy_pwds = *path_copy;
                dup_flag = 1;
                copy_pwds++;
            }else if (( *path_copy != '\\') && ( *path_copy != '/' ))  {
                *copy_pwds = *path_copy;
                dup_flag = 0;
                copy_pwds++;
            }
```

Very complicated logic in my opinion. You could just track the last character.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What is plain english equivalent of this sentence : "I'd advocate that the comment is written by @CaptainObvious bot which is run in the 2nd monitor chat room." ?

Comment: @ShivendraMishra, in the 2nd monitor chat room on this site, there is a bot posting recent questions, and it just turned out that it has the funny name. Don't mind it, I'm just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

> Removing multiple slashes from path

Removing repeated slashes, in place, can be done simply:

```
char *RemoveRepeatedSlashes(char *s) {
  if (s) {
    const char *src = s;
    char *dst = s;
    // while (*dst = *src) {  // Too code-golfish
    while ((*dst = *src) != '\0') {
      do {
        src++;
      } while ((*dst == '/' || *dst == '\\')  && (*src == '/' || *src == '\\'));
      dst++;
    }
  }  
  return s;
}
```

Modify `0` to `'\0'` and `while (*dst = *src)` to your coding style

---

If code needs to form a copy, let the calling routine handle allocation.  If needed, create a string duplication function.

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
  size_t sz = strlen(s) + 1;
  char *dest = malloc(sz);
  if (dest) {
    memcpy(dest, s, sz);
  }
  return dest;
}        

// Sample use
char *StrippedPath = RemoveRepeatedSlashes(strdup(OringialPath));
```

Right-sizing the allocated memory to account for the stripped slashes in only needed in tight memory usage.  Recommend to simply use with original buffer size and not `realloc()`.

---

Path validation should be done with a separate function than the above two, take a `const char *` and return a simple result.  Path validation cannot meet "Code must be platform independent" as the correctness of a path is very platform dependent.

```
bool validate_path(const char* path);
```

Comment: What about `//implementation-defined` and `\\UNC-path`?

Comment: @Oskar Skog Comment unclear, please expand.

Comment: I was referring to the comments to the question by 200_success and Jörg W Mittag.  `//foo` should not be turned into `/foo` because double leading slash may have a special meaning.

Comment: @Oskar Skog "//foo should not be turned into /foo"  is a platform dependent issue  - _in general_. In this tagged `Linux` and  maybe `windows`, leading slash slash is OK.  IMO, OP's `validate_path ()` coding goal is too convoluted and path de-slashing and path validation need to be separate functions.

Comment: `while (*dst = *src)` is a terrible coding style.  In order to use it, you must disable useful compiler warnings. Sooner or later, you will get bitten.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree `while (*dst = *src)` has weaknesses.  Yet rather than only attribute a terrible coding style, suggest a better alternative.

Comment: To avoid combining the assignment with the test implicitly, you can make it explicit like this: `while ((*dst = *src) != '\0')`.